# DNS Server communication issue, timeout

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, ubuntu-20.04

I have set up a DNS server with both master and slave in Ubuntu 20.04.5. All the configurations are made properly. But when I am doing nslookup, it's giving the following error:

**;; communications error to x.x.x.x#53: timed out**

I have checked the firewall status, it's disabled. I have googled various resources but not finding the exact solution to this error.

Please help me with the error.

Comment: Well can you ping x.x.x.x? What kind of other torubleshooting did you do?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. My dns servers are local they answer only to lan requests, everything works as expected, except this nslookup error.

as example:

```
sudo nslookup
[sudo] password for user:
> google.ro
;; communications error to 192.168.1.2#53: timed out
Server:         192.168.1.2
Address:        192.168.1.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.ro
Address: 142.251.39.35
Name:   google.ro
Address: 2a00:1450:400d:80d::200
```

where 192.168.1.2 is primary dns, same if i set the server to secondary dns 192.168.1.3

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1199812)